# Magento 2 - How to add custom discount in cart programmatically?

Tags: magento2, cart, discount

I want to apply custom discount amount to cart programmatically. I have tried doing it in following 2 ways, none of which work:

**METHOD 1:**

I tried following the default way in which Magento2 applies `sales-rule` discounts. I did it by creating following files in my module:

**etc\sales.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Sales:etc/sales.xsd">
    <section name="quote">
        <group name="totals">
            <item name="discount" instance="Vendorname\Modulenmae\Model\CustomFolderName\Quote\Discount" sort_order="400"/>
        </group>
    </section>
</config>
```

**frontend\layout\checkout_cart_index.xml**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
     <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.totals">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="block-totals" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="before_grandtotal" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="discount" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">My Custom Discount</item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**Model File**

```
class Discount extends \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total\AbstractTotal
{
    public function collect(
            \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote,
            \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\ShippingAssignmentInterface $shippingAssignment,
            \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total $total
        ) {

            parent::collect($quote, $shippingAssignment, $total);

            $label          = 'My Custom Discount';
            $discountAmount = -10;              
            $total->setDiscountDescription($label);
            $total->setDiscountAmount($discountAmount);
            $total->setBaseDiscountAmount($discountAmount);
            $total->setSubtotalWithDiscount($total->getSubtotal() + $discountAmount);
            $total->setBaseSubtotalWithDiscount($total->getBaseSubtotal() + $discountAmount);
            return $this;
        }
        //fetch function is also defined in this class. Since it is only used for display purposes I have not added its code in this question.
}
```

However, with this method, my custom discount gets applied but Magento's default `sales rules` like `coupon code`, etc. stop working. They throw errors like `Invalid Coupon Code` even when the coupon code is completely valid. If I revert my changes, the default coupon codes start working again.

**METHOD 2:**

Another method i tried is applying discount by observing the `sales_quote_collect_totals_after` event. It is working fine, but i think method 1 might be the best way to achieve it.

Any ideas as to how can I do it correctly ?

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/magepal/stackexchange/tree/develop/104112 . The discount work with other coupons and display the correct total but the break down of the discount `fetch()` not display correctly

Comment: @R.S - Thank you so much. With your code there was 1 issue, discount coupon got applied but it removed my custom discount and added its coupon discount. I have made minor change to add both discounts, so when custom discount is in cart and coupon is applied it will add both. https://github.com/parekhreena/stackexchange/blob/develop/104112/TestDiscount/Model/Quote/Discount.php . Please add it as answer and i will accept it

Comment: There is an issue in Admin where it will automatically  apply the discount before any item is added. So you will need to check to make sure the total is greater than zero and check to make sure that the total is always greater than total discount (so you don't have a negative total).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thanks @R.S. . I found the solution by referring repo created by @R.S. here: https://github.com/magepal/stackexchange/tree/develop/104112 after some minor modifications.

**sales.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Sales:etc/sales.xsd">
    <section name="quote">
        <group name="totals">
            <item name="testdiscount" instance="MagePal\TestDiscount\Model\Quote\Discount" sort_order="500"/>
        </group>
    </section>
</config>
```

**Model file**

```
public function collect(
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote,
        \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\ShippingAssignmentInterface $shippingAssignment,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total $total
    ) {
        //Fix for discount applied twice
        $items = $shippingAssignment->getItems();
        if (!count($items)) {
            return $this;
        }

        parent::collect($quote, $shippingAssignment, $total);
        //$address             = $shippingAssignment->getShipping()->getAddress();
        $label               = 'My Custom Discount';
        $discountAmount      = -10;   
        $appliedCartDiscount = 0;
        if($total->getDiscountDescription()) {
            // If a discount exists in cart and another discount is applied, the add both discounts.
            $appliedCartDiscount = $total->getDiscountAmount();
            $discountAmount      = $total->getDiscountAmount()+$discountAmount;
        $label               = $total->getDiscountDescription().', '.$label;
        }    

        $total->setDiscountDescription($label);
    $total->setDiscountAmount($discountAmount);
    $total->setBaseDiscountAmount($discountAmount);
        $total->setSubtotalWithDiscount($total->getSubtotal() + $discountAmount);
        $total->setBaseSubtotalWithDiscount($total->getBaseSubtotal() + $discountAmount);

       if(isset($appliedCartDiscount)) {
        $total->addTotalAmount($this->getCode(), $discountAmount - $appliedCartDiscount);
        $total->addBaseTotalAmount($this->getCode(), $discountAmount - $appliedCartDiscount);
    } else {
        $total->addTotalAmount($this->getCode(), $discountAmount);
        $total->addBaseTotalAmount($this->getCode(), $discountAmount);
    }

        return $this;
    }
```

**checkout_cart_index.xml**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.totals">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="block-totals" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="before_grandtotal" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="testdiscount" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">My Discount</item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**checkout_index_index.xml**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="sidebar" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="summary" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="totals" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="testdiscount" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">My Discount</item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Fetch is not showing the custom discount description. I have opened its ticket here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/3594

Comment: Hello Reena, your answer is fine and working perfect, but one issue create..
Coupon code is not working when use above answer..

Comment: Ohh Sorry for my comment.. My small mistake here. Now Perfect.. Thanks Reena.

Comment: Discount is working fine but discount detail not displaying on cart page, Can you please let me know the fix. I have checked the ticket and found same discount file

Comment: some time discount applied twice , can you please let me know quick fix for this

Comment: @mjdevloper- this code works just fine and doesn't apply discount twice. kindly post your question separately on this site and either I or someone else from the community will get back to you.

Comment: Get error when place order like:The requested Payment Method is not available. ,when applied discount more then 50% of grand total.

Comment: @paresh -  Then check minimum allowed amount of your payment method in admin panel. The code works fine. and upvote the answer if you're using it.

Comment: There is nothing set in minimum allowed amount in payment method ,i think           if there is problem of minimum amount then that payment method not display in payment method step.

Comment: what about adding custom coupon name to apply the custom discount?

Comment: @ReenaParekh, I've installed your module form git, Issues is discount is applied but there's error message "Coupon Code is not valid",. ??

Any idea ?? OR I missing something ?

Comment: @LazyCoder your quote's coupon code is not matching/found.  Debug \Magento\Quote\Model\CouponManagement::set and \Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Create::_processActionData , these 2 places through that error. This should help you trace the problem

Comment: How can i change discount Label ?

Comment: @SURENDERSINGH Try changing here -  <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">My Discount</item>

Comment: @ReenaParekh changed but not working

Comment: @ReenaParekh DIscount is always applied twice for me. Tried to modify the code in various ways but still the discount applies twice.

Comment: @ReenaParekh, I need to apply discount amount for each quote item in the cart. right now discount is getting applied on full cart total. Also applied discount is nowhere showing in admin order grid view

Comment: @ReenaParekh, Can you please post an answer how to set discount on each quote item?

Comment: This worked perfectly. I have also added the code in answer which will fix the issue for discount apply twice. +1 on your answer. Helped a lot :)

Comment: Hi @Reena it is working fine for me but at the case of 0 Total amount, free method is not showing so unable to place order. Can you fix this please? it is very urgent.