# Magento 2 : How to add custom discount Programatically?

Tags: magento2, discount

I need to apply custom custom discount in cart ?

There's option for applying this in M1. Check here.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24308094/magento-dynamically-change-discount-cost-in-cart

How can i do same thing in M2 ??

Thanks in Advance.

community-edition

Comment: https://webkul.com/blog/set-custom-discount-fee-cart-magento-2/

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/104112/magento-2-how-to-add-custom-discount-in-cart-programmatically

Comment: Both reference use same method, They have override core collect method, I would like to perform same thing from my custom controller.