# set discount amount while creating order progrmmatically in magento2

Tags: magento2, orders, sales-order, quote

I am creating order pro-grammatically.

I have referred below code

https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/how-to-create-order-programmatically-in-magento-2/

My requirement is to set discount amount for each cart item.

The discount amount is 5. This can be varied based the product id which i am fetching from external api

I tried below code for that.

```
 $quote->setDiscountAmount(5);
```

after the line

```
$quote->addProduct($product,$buyRequest);
```

It is not working. Can anyone help me to achieve this functionality.

Thanks for your help

**Update**

As from Amit suggestion i used below code.

**Vendor\Module\etc\sales.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Sales:etc/sales.xsd">
<section name="quote">
    <group name="totals">
        <item name="testdiscount" instance="Vendor\Module\Model\Quote\Discount" sort_order="500"/>
    </group>
</section>
```

**Vendor\Module\Model\Quote\Discount.php**

```
namespace X247commerce\CustomerService\Model\Quote;

 class Discount extends 
 \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total\AbstractTotal
 {   
 protected $_priceCurrency;

  public function __construct(
   \Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency
  ){
   $this->_priceCurrency = $priceCurrency;
  }

public function collect(
   \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote,
   \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\ShippingAssignmentInterface $shippingAssignment,
   \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total $total
 )
{
   parent::collect($quote, $shippingAssignment, $total);
       $baseDiscount = 10;
       $discount =  $this->_priceCurrency->convert($baseDiscount);
       $total->addTotalAmount('customdiscount', -$discount);
       $total->addBaseTotalAmount('customdiscount', -$baseDiscount);
       $total->setBaseGrandTotal($total->getBaseGrandTotal() - $baseDiscount);
       $quote->setCustomDiscount(-$discount);
       $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
       $objectManager->get('Psr\Log\LoggerInterface')->info('discount'.$discount);      
      $objectManager->get('Psr\Log\LoggerInterface')->info(json_encode($quote->getData()));
   return $this;
  }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You cannot give discount amount using a simple setter function `setDiscountAmount()`.

At Magento,discount amount calculation on [Cart Price rule](https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/marketing/price-rules-cart.html). So, it means you have ***to applied coupon on to your code /apply Cart price rules programmatically to this Quote object***.

Create a Cart Price rule at admin and apply coupon code at quote programmatically to this Quote object.

> `$quote->setCouponCode($couponCode)->collectTotals()->save();`

### Update

**If you want to apply the custom discount as per as your desire then you have to implement custom discount , and this discount does not depend on Magento cart price rules.**

Check the below aricles, how you can implement custom discount

https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/how-add-custom-discount-magento-2.html
https://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/how-to-add-magento-2-custom-discount/
[Magento 2 - How to add custom discount in cart programmatically?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/104112/magento-2-how-to-add-custom-discount-in-cart-programmatically)

Comment: I don't like to create coupon code. can we set discount amount to the total, that value will be varied based on the api I am calling.

Comment: The value 5 can be varied because the amount value i am reading from external api, how to set discount amount to total in that way

Comment: Each and every time i can't create the coupon code to set, so is there anyway to set discount amount only please

Comment: hello @Amit, I still have some questions, I need to set custom discount amount for each cart item not for whole cart. in that case how can i use those snippets
Also will it show in admin sales order grid, that custom discount

Comment: You will get quote object  at `collect(` from ` $quote` ,So you can get quote items and calculate the total.

Comment: hi Amit, It would be helpful if u update me the code, Also will it show in sales order view info page as discount amount?

Comment: you have asked some question which needs good of amount code and every long answer And that is NOT possible for me . If I will go to an answer then I will take a very good amount of time of mine. For now, that is not possible for me(Sorry to say that). I guess that you get some clue about your required from my post  and will use those post for your integration of this requirement

Comment: yes that's fine. I'll try it, can u confirm will the applied discount amount will be shown in order view page?

Comment: anyway tried above solution which didn't work for me, discount not getting applied for me

Comment: it should work, You might be doing some  mistake

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95954/discussion-between-manjunath-and-amit-bera).

Comment: Pls check the chat, I have followed as it is in the links u provided. and updated my code pls check where i am wrong here

Comment: hi @Amit, could you update me how to apply discount on each quote item please?